# why printing to "stdout" not executing sequentially?

Tags: c, stdout

My friend gave me a riddle. I run it. but not getting expected output. 
Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
       while(1)
       {
              fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
              fprintf(stderr,"hello-err");
              sleep(1);
       }
       return 0;
}
```

the output doesn't printing hello-out.
Instead it's printing like this infinitely:

```
hello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-err
```

Then I tried like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() 
{
     int i = 0;

     while(i <= 5)
     {
          fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
          fprintf(stderr,"hello-err");
          sleep(1);
          i++;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

the optput is:

```
hello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-outhello-outhello-outhello-outhello-outhello-out
```

In C language instructions execute line by line. But why it is not following here?

Comment: A C program has *two* output streams. It is up to your platform how it presents those. Unless you make an effort to record the two streams separately, it won't be terribly illuminating to worry about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File IO behavior is determined by the system and if you want to keep that order you must explicitly `fflush`. See this program below:

```
     while(i <= 5)
     {
          fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
          fflush(stdout);
          fprintf(stderr,"hello-err");
          fflush(stderr);
          sleep(1);
          i++;
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is output buffering.

By default, `stdout` is buffered: if it's connected to a terminal it's line-buffered, otherwise it's fully-buffered. When it's line-buffered, that means that nothing is printed until you print a newline, the buffer fills up, or the buffer is flushed explicitly. Since you're not printing newlines, the output doesn't show up until the program exits, because all stdio buffers are flushed at that time.

`stderr`, on the other hand, is not buffered by default. So anything written to it appears immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the buffering of `stdout` info. Makes it much clear.